# exact sequence of groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $0 \to G' \xrightarrow{\text{f}} G \xrightarrow{\text{g}} G'' \to 0$ be an exact sequence. On page 16 of Lang's *Algebra* (third edition), he says that if $H$ is the kernel of $G$, then this sequence is "essentially the same" as the sequence $0 \to H \to G \to G/H \to 0$. He says that in particular, we have the following commutative diagram:

[image]

Why is this the case? I guess we just set the middle arrow to be the identity, and we can set the first arrow vertical arrow to be $f$, but what about the last vertical arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last vertical arrow is just the projection on $G/H$ which maps $g \rightarrow [g]$ to it's class in $G/H$. An Element $[x]=0 \in G/H \Longleftrightarrow x \in H$, so $H$ is the kernel of the projection (and the projection is obviously surjective) hence the sequence is exact.

Also the first arrow of course is not $f$, but the inclusion of $H$ into $G$. Any Group that can be mapped by an injective homomorphism into $G$ can be seen as a subgroup of $G$.

Sorry, these were the horizontal arrows of course.. For the last vertical arrow: let $a \in G''$. Take a preimage $a'$ in $G$, then project onto $G/H$ should work. (Remains to show that this is well defined).

And why is this well defined? Suppose $a', a''$ two preimages then $a'-a'' \in kerf = H$, so it is $[a']= [a''] \in G/H$.

Comment: How can we map $G'' \to G/H$? We have a projection from $G \to G/H$ but not from $G'' \to G/H$. Let me clarify, I know what the horizontal arrows are, but not the vertical ones which make the diagram commutative.

Comment: Yes, lack of English skills. I'm sorry. I edited my reply.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded harsh. Thanks for the reply, I understand the situation now.

Comment: No worries. My fault.